# How to server-side cache ASP.NET custom HttpHandler response

Tags: asp.net, caching, httphandler

I've got a custom HttpHandler in my ASP.NET application, that basically builds and returns a javascript object.  I have no experience with server-side caching, and my (possibly incompetent) google searches aren't returning anything basic enough to get me started.

Could anyone provide a very simple example to give me an idea of how to access and use the server-side cache from a custom HttpHandler, or, leave some links to get me started?  Thanks a lot.

Additional info: I'm on IIS 6, and my code-behind is in C# (although a VB example would work as well).

Comment: Would be helpful is you mentioned if you are on IIS 6 or IIS7.

Comment: @Eric, what would be the difference between IIS 6 and IIS 7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very simple example to get you started, without locking or error handling:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) {
  MyObject thing = context.Cache["object_name"];
  if (thing == null) {
    thing = new MyObject();
    context.Cache["object_name"] = thing;
  }

  // use thing here to process request
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I was suspecting that this was the way to go, but the answers I found online were (I think) assuming people already knew this much.