# How to cache handler images?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, handler

I have blob data's approx 85000 images i am generating it from handler and stored in to database as image datatype now when i render it into a webpage it working very slow obviously so i want to find some middle solution for this one probably **cache** i think its a best solution for me so can any one give me some idea about this one my code looks like this

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {

context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, byteSeq);
                byteSeq = strm.Read(buffer, 0, 8192);
}
```

and image

```
     <img  src='<%# "handler/product?"+Email.Encryptdes(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"product_id").ToString()) %>'/>
```

so what to do now i can not see my page loading at 30 seconds
Should i go for folder option for images?

Comment: Is it required to store images in DB? I would say better you store images in some folder and put that path in DB. This will also reduce your DB size and number of requests you are making to DB.

Comment: I agree with alok_dida plus caching will not avoid the initial page load performance hit.

Comment: Ya i know @alok_dida  but myproblem is i have to revert all the things that would be messy so i am finding some middlest option i know folder option is best but is that only option remains for me?

Comment: Ya @IrishChieftain but what to do now?

Comment: Check some of the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720046/setting-httphandler-isreusable-property/3720129#3720129 but it would help if you could narrow down the problem. If your images are all big then it may not be the SQL query. Are you loading images into a ListView or such? If so, then set page size to something less, etc...

Comment: I am using repeater control for this one

Comment: How many images are you loading up on page load and what's the average image size?

Comment: Avg image size is 80kb i am showing 30images on page load

Comment: That's contributing to it. Images alone are 2.4 MB plus rest of page overhead. Reduce page size to 10 and check the difference? (Empty your cache between each attempt).

Comment: Ok @IrishChieftain i am replying you after checking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best approach is to store the [images in folders and the paths in the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay?lq=1).

Next option would be to check overall size of images being downloaded on one page load. Try reducing this to at most, about 10 images; set page size of your Repeater to 10.

You can also add caching but this will not in any way help speed up the first page load for everyone that comes to your site, and it is the first impressions that count.

Finally, set IsReusable property of your handler to false unless you're defensively coding against possibility of [multi-threading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2057394/should-i-set-isreusable-to-true-in-my-httphandlers/2057475#2057475) issues.

Comment: I would say that's solution for me !!

Comment: Glad to help. This is informative: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsDynamicImageGenerationASPNETControllersRoutingIHttpHandlersAndRunAllManagedModulesForAllRequests.aspx

Comment: If images served with server side output caching than it more or less does not really matter where images are coming from... There are plenty reasons to go FS or DB way of storing images...

Comment: I am going for the folder option now

Answer (score 4):

You can set cache in the handler itself as follows

```
context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
context.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10));
```

So if the browser ask for the same data it is cached for 10 minutes.

For further improvement you can save the image in a local folder and then set the path.

Few useful links

1. [How to use output caching on .ashx handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109768/how-to-use-output-caching-on-ashx-handler)
2. [Cache an object in a .ashx handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14297580/cache-an-object-in-a-ashx-handler)
3. [How to server-side cache ASP.NET custom HttpHandler response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852462/how-to-server-side-cache-asp-net-custom-httphandler-response)

Comment: Thanks for reply shekhar i would like one more little help is there anyway to automatically tell browser to update this image incase user change image then what to do?

Comment: @dholakiyaankit you can create use server side cache if it is in server cache then provide else create a cache and then provide the cache (on the basis of query string or any other condition). Set the cache expire time as feasible.